# Swift NSDate and print(NSDate)

Tags: swift, printing, nsdate

my current time is 4:50 PM my timezone is UTC + 1

why it gives me date in UTC when I print it. and in Debug Area it's UTC

I can't understand this 1 hour difference between the same NSDate()

NSDate()          // prints: "Oct 2, 2015, 4:50 PM"
print(NSDate())   // prints: "2015-10-02 15:50:52 +0000\n"

Comment: Where is  this happening? Playground, lldb, somewhere else?

Comment: @zaph not only in Playground also in Xcode Project.
to test it I created an extension to NSDate that will display the hour of the date.
When I print NSDate.hour it returns the exact hour that I am expecting in my time zone
and When I print NSDate it returns the hour in UTC

I'll try to report it as you suggested.

Thank you :)

Comment: it is best to update the question instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question is about the Playground the answer is because that is how the Swift developers decided to handle default printing of dates in the Playground.

If you want a specific format use `NSDateFormatter`.

If you disagree and feel that it should be changed then go to [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com). (I have done that and the change I requested was made, the process can work).